# d3 v4 accessing x and y value from Object _data_

Tags: javascript, d3.js

d.x and d.y inside the transform attribute return 'undefined'.

```
   this.nodeElements = this.nodeGroup.selectAll('circle')
  .data(this.sensors);

console.log(this.sensors[0].x); // this returns the correct x value


const nodeEnter = this.nodeElements
  .enter()
  .append('svg:g')
  .attr('transform', d => 'translate(' + d.x + ', ' + d.y + ')');
```

- how can I get the defined d.x or d.y  ? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was actually related to ionic life cycles. Thank you.